# Cómo obtener la ruta de mi proyecto para luega crear una carpeta en una parte exacta de él

Tags: java, webservice

Necesito crear una carpeta en la carpeta (ruta_dinamica)/web/img/empresas de mi proyecto, pero la ruta debe ser dinámica, ya que el proyecto no siempre se encontrará en una ruta especifica. Esto se aplica en un webservice debido a requerimientos, ya que ahí me enviarán el nombre de la carpeta a crear.

Answer (score 0):

Nadie me pudo ayudar, después de mezclar información y hacer un par de pruebas pude hacerlo perfectamente.
Dejo el código por si a alguien le sirve.
Ojo, el -menos 35 dependerá de algunos factores de su proyecto.

```
/**
 * This is a sample web service operation
 * @param folderName
 * @return 
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "createFolder")
public String createFolder(@WebParam(name = "folderName") String folderName) throws IOException {
    String rutaBruta = this.getClass().getResource("").getPath();
    rutaBruta = rutaBruta.substring(0, rutaBruta.length() - 35);
    String ruta = rutaBruta + "/web/img/empresas/"+folderName;
    File archivo = new File(ruta);
    archivo.mkdirs();
    return "Su carpete fue creada en la siguiente ruta: "+ruta;
}
```